# versions:use-releases for properties

Tags: java, maven, maven-versions-plugin

As I understand, `versions:use-releases` does not update properties that are used to define versions in dependencies.

Is it possible to update these properties as well? I saw that we have a `versions:update-properties`, but it is meant to update versions to the latest versions, not just replace Snapshots by releases.

An example:

Assume you have dependency like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.something</groupId>
    <artifactId>coutil</artifactId>
    <version>${coutil.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and `coutil.version` is defined to be `7.0.0-SNAPSHOT`.

Without the property (i.e. with `7.0.0-SNAPSHOT` directly in the version tag), `versions:use-releases` would replace `7.0.0-SNAPSHOT` by `7.0.0` (if this exists). Now with the indirection of the property, this no longer happens.

I tried to solve the problem by using `versions:update-properties` where I disallowed major, minor and incremental updates (`-DallowMajorUpdates=false` etc.), but it had the unexpected consequence of replacing `7.0.0-SNAPSHOT` by `7.0.1-RC0002` instead of `7.0.0`.

Comment: Please add an example for better explanation

Comment: @Jens Thanks for the suggestion, I added some information.

Comment: a bug has been opened here: https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues/336

Answer (score -2):

You can update any property with relative fresh version of versions plugin. 
(I guess, you need at least vetsion 2.5 )
e.g:

```
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.7:set-property -Dproperty=MyProperty -DnewVersion=MyValue org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.7:commit
```

Comment: I do not want to set an explicit version, but replace Snapshots by Releases.