# Versions Maven Plugin : do not update to last release available

Tags: maven, versions-maven-plugin, maven-versions-plugin

Let's consider I have a dependency in my `pom.xml` like this :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
  <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

For each build, I'd like the version of this dependency to be updated if the release exists.
Thus, I expect the version to be updated from *1.0-SNAPSHOT* to *1.0*, **even if version 2.0 has been released**.

It's possible with [Versions Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html), executing `mvn versions:use-releases`. Fine.

Now, the version is set in a property. The `pom.xml` looks like this :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
  <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
  <version>${my.version}</version>
</dependency>

<properties>
  <my.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</my.version>
</properties>
```

Same as before, I'd like like the version of this dependency to be updated if the release exists.

It looked possible with the same [Versions Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html), executing `mvn versions:update-properties`. But, with this goal, the version is updated to the **last release available** (e.g. *2.0* in our case) instead of *1.0*.

Any idea of how to get the same behavior as `use-release` goal with `update-properties` goal ?

Comment: I asked the same thing some time ago, https://stackoverflow.com/q/54940280/927493, but unfortunately no helpful answers...